# Iterations with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, iteration

I haven't really worked much with asynchronous code so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong/something could go wrong. Right now of all the test cases that I have done, my code has worked but I'm not sure if I will get side effects or not.

I won't post any of the business logic, just the iteration part with the asynchronous function in it:

```
function asyncInIteration(skinArray)  {
   request("/someaddresshere", function (err, response, data)  {

      var left = something.length;

      for (var i = 0;i<something.length;i++) (function (i) {
          request("/someotheraddress", function (err, response, data) {
             if (--left === 0)  {
                 console.log("End of for loop");
             }
          })
      })(i);
   });
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do with this code is loop through an array (`skinArray`) and add values to it via sending HTTP requests.

The most important thing for me is that:

1. Every value of `i` should only be repeated once.
2. When I call `--left === 0`, that has to be called once, and only after all values of `i` have been gone through.

If someone wants to see the code with the business logic, you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/Ep7fjiHr).

Comment: This will properly detect when the last `request()` operation finishes.  Do you need the `request()` results in order when you're done?  Are you OK with all the `request()` operations being launch in parallel (all in-flight at the same time)?

Comment: Yeah I don't mind if they aren't in order. The only thing that matters for me is that everything in the array only iterates once and the --left === 0 conditional is at the end of the for loop.

Comment: Your wording makes me wonder if you understand the actual sequence of events here.  First, your `for` loop runs and initiates all the requests.  At that point, the `for` loop is done and any code that comes after it executes.  Then, some time later the first `request()` finishes and calls its callback.  Then, sometime later, the next does.  Then, finally the last one completes and your `left` variable will hit `0`.  The `for` loop was done long before this.

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash to make Your iteration "readable".

And use async to handle end of asynchronous iteration to properly respond with "end of loop"

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var something = ['a','b','c'];
function asyncInIteration(skinArray)  {

   request("/someaddresshere", function (err, response, data)  {
      var functions = []; // array of functions that will be called

      // generating array of functions
      _.times(something.length, 
          function() {
              // pushing function to functions list
              functions.push(function(done){ // "next" is necessary to inform async module about finishing call
                  request("/someotheraddress", function (err, response, data) {
                      // doing something
                      console.log("\n--------");
                      console.log("RESPONSE:", data);
                      console.log("--------\n");
                      done();
                  });
              });
          });

      // can change to .series if You want to make it synchronous (not parallel)
      async.parallel(functions, function(){
          console.log('End of loop');
      });
   });
}
```

P.S. In fact my code looks like not so simple, but there is no another elegant way to control asynchronousity. Maybe Promise object will be easy to work, but I don't think it's suitable for current task.